# Distinguishing spell check from link

Tags: html, hyperlinks, css, spell-checking

I want to display misspelled words within text in HTML that are detected by a spell checker. I simply put the misspelled words in a `<span>` element, and made the color red, and the text-decoration underline. However, the text also has hyperlinks, which are in the default design (color is blue/purple, and text-decoration is underline), and they look similar. How can I make the misspelled words be more distinct from links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 most popular ways of indicating misspelled text are to underline it with either red dotted line or red wavy line – the practice adopted by word processors and browsers.

The easiest way is to set dotted underline: just apply `border-bottom: dotted 1px red` property to your `<span>` element.

The implementation of wavy line is a way trickier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821365/how-to-put-a-waved-line-under-misspelled-words-html